# How to save having the same name attribute value in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

what is the approach of saving same name attribute in Laravel 5.5? I am not if I'm doing right of grouping them in foreach loop and where to put the save method.

```
<input type="text" name="aka" value="The Magnificent" />    
@foreach ($listTalkOperationTime as $data)
   <input type="number" name="startHours[]"value="{{ $data->starthour }}" />
   <input type="number" name="startMins[]" value="{{ $data->startmin }}" />
   <input type="number" name="endHours[]" value="{{ $data->endhour }}" />
   <input type="number" name="endMins[]" value="{{ $data->endmin }}" />
   <button type="button">Submit</button>
@endforeach
```

This is what's in my head

```
$model = new User;
$model->aka = $request->aka;
foreach ($request->startHours as $so) {
  $model->starthours = $so;
}
foreach ($request->startMins $sm) {
  $model->starthours = $sm;
}
...
$model->save()
```

Comment: `foreach ($request->startHours as $so) {
  $model->starthours = $so;
}` would assume `N` number of `starthours` columns in your `users` table. Which is not possible. You should add your db structure in the question. Probably you would need relationships.

Comment: Why your inputs are `array`?